# SAS: Compare values between two numbers to make separate buckets

Tags: sas

I'm trying to compare multiple sets of data by putting them in separate groups between two numbers. Originally I had statements like,

```
if COLUMN1 gt 0 and COLUMN1 LE 1000 then PRICE_GROUP = 1000;
```

I had this going up by 1000 to 100,000. The only problem is that once I counted how many were in each price_group, some price_groups were missing (57,000 had no values so when I would count(Price_group) it would not appear for some groups). The solution I think is to make a table with the bounds for each, and then compare the actual value vs the upper and lower bound.

```
proc iml;

  mat = j(100,2,0);

  total = 100000;

  mat[1,1] = 0;
  mat[1,2] = mat[1,1] + (total/100);
  do i = 2 to nrow(mat);
        mat[i,1] = mat[i-1,1] +  (total/100);
        mat[i,2] = mat[i,1] + (total/100);
  end;

create dataset from mat;
append from mat;
quit;
```

This creates the table which I can compare the values, but is there an easier way besides proc iml? I was next going to do a loop to compare each value with the two columns and create a new column on the table to have the count in each bucket. This still seems like an intensive process that is inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IML isn't a terrible solution, but there are a few others depending on what exactly you're doing.

The most common is `proc format`.  Create a format that manages each bucket, like so:

```
proc format;
value buckets
0-1000 = 1000
1000<-2000 = 2000
...
other="NA";
quit;
```

Then you can either use the format (or informat) to create a new variable with the bucketed value, or even better, use the format on the fly (ie, in proc means or whatnot) which not only means you don't have to rewrite the dataset, but you can swap formats on and off depending on how many buckets you want (say, `buckets100` format or `buckets20` and whatnot).

Second, your specific question looks like it's solveable just using math:

```
data want;
set have;
bucket = &total/100*(1+floor(column1/(&total/100)));
run;
```

although obviously that doesn't work for every example.

Third, you could use a hash lookup table, if you are unable to use formats (such as there are two or more elements that determine the bucket).  If that's useful I can expand on that, or just google about as those are very commonly used for lookups in SAS.  That's the closest solution to the IML solution inside a regular datastep.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table with groups:

```
data group_table;
do price_group=1000 to 100000 by 1000;
output;
end;
run;
```

Then left join the grouping/comparison table with this new table using price_group as key:

```
proc sql;
    create table price_group_compare as
    select L.price_group,R.group1_count,R.group2_count
    from group_table as L, group_counts as R
    on L.price_group = R.price_group;
quit;
```